# React - Mobx Validation input Field

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I have been searching for a MOBX validation on a input field, but I havent be able to find anything, I found "MobX-input" which requires a form but I dont have any form. another one that I found was "mobx-react-form" with ValidatorJs which again uses form. any hint or example would be appreciated . I just wanna be able to use it on plain input field

```
 <Input placeholder="FirstName" type="text"
 defaultValue={Contact.FirstName} onChange={(e) => handler(e)} />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple validation is pretty easy to create on your own with MobX.  For a single field like this, a simple method for validating the function could look like this:

in the component we have an error field that only shows if the input has been submitted (which could be triggered by a button push or whatever)

```
return <div>
<input placeholder="FirstName" type="text"
 defaultValue={Contact.FirstName} onChange={(e) => handler(e)} />
{submitted && <span className="error-message">{Contact.FirstNameError}</span>}
</div>;
```

In the observable class (I used the non-decorator style), we define the field as an observable, and an error message class as a computed value.

```
class Contact {
  constructor() {
     extendObservable({
       submitted: false,
       FirstName: observable(),
       FirstNameError: computed(() => {
          if(this.FirstName.length < 10) {
             return 'First name must be at least 10 characters long';
          }
          // further validation here
          return undefined;
       })
     })
  }

}
```

You could easily add an extra `hasError` computed value that just checks to see if `FirstNameError` has a value.

This method scales to a few inputs.  If you start having a bunch of them, then you'd want to look into an abstraction like a 3rd party library or something you write yourself to manage your validations.  You could write a function to generate the computed properties you need based on a little configuration.